# Scilab automatic deletion of zero elements

Tags: arrays, matrix, zero, scilab

How to avoid deleting of zero elements at the end of array? For example i have a matrix (array) [1,0,1,1,1,0]. When i find this array as return value in my function, it needs to return that what i wrote, but it returns 1 0 1 1 1. How to avoid that kind of automatic deletion of zero elements?

Answer (score 2):

Following example works.

```
function [array] = returnCompleteArray()
    array  = [1,0,1,1,1,0];
endfunction

a = returnCompleteArray();

disp(a);
```

How are you assigning the array within the function? Could you provide your code?